# Cannot retrieve javascript cookie after dropping cookie before redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies

My page HTML contains a span (with text) whose `onClick = "goDropShip();"`

The page contains a script that contains:

```
function goDropShip() {

    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(24*60*60*1000));
    document.cookie = "dropShip=true; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    window.location.href="http://www.domain.com";

}
```

I have verified, with "`alert()`", that the function is in fact executing.  And testing the cookie immediately after dropping it is successful.  However, after the redirect, the cookie seems to be empty.

www.domain.com's index.html (which receives this redirect) has a script with the following:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("dropShip=true") >= 0  ) {
    window.location = "http://www.domain.com/processDropShip";
}
```

However, the cookie appears to be completely blank after the redirect.

I am trying `.indexOf()` only because attempts to retrieve the cookie specifically by name have also failed, so I am trying to find the cookie in the entire document.cookie text.

I am probably just not using the cookies properly, or I do not know how to.

Forgive the fact that "dropShip" doesn't seem to make sense in this context, but I am having to obfuscate the details for security reasons.  But the only thing I have changed is the cookie name.

As always, thanks for any help.

Comment: Cookies are domain specific. Is that the same domain?

Comment: If the domain you're setting the cookie on isn't `http://www.domain.com` (www. makes a different as does http or https, must be the same subdomain etc) then you won't be able to read the cookie on the other side. If however, you're using the same domain, then you should make sure you're also specifying the path for the cookie to exist. e.g. `path=/`

Comment: Ultimater, can you give an example of the path in code?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the domain your are setting the cookie from and redirecting to are same, you just need to have the path set to `/` while adding the cookie so that it's accessible throughout the domain.

`document.cookie = "dropShip=true; path=/; expires="+date.toGMTString();`